# ios BLE: Does CoreBLE provide any indication that unpairing has occurred?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Let's say an app is connected to a BLE device and that device decides to unpair. Is there any way for an app to efficiently learn about the unpairing? For instance is there a protocol method that informs the app about unpairings?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way in the Bluetooth standard to unpair a device so the other end knows about it. You must do it manually on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Core Bluetooth does not offer any visibility on the pairing or bonding state of peripherals. You are only notified of connection/disconnection events.